Table Rename Swaps Impacting Views
I have a table that is in use constantly during the day.  In addition, it reloads once a day, and the reload takes a long time.  Because of how long it takes to reload and the locks that happen, we load a staging table and then dynamically swap them by renaming the tables.
So specifically, we have:
mdm.item_master       => primary table
mdm.item_master_swap  => copy of same

A stored proc loads mdm.item_master_swap daily, and then we:

rename mdm.item_master to mdm.item_master_temp
rename mdm.item_master_swap to mdm.item_master
rename mdm.item_master_temp to mdm.item_master_swap

effectively switching item_master and item_master_swap.
The problem I'm having is any views that associate to item_master now associate to item_master_swap.  Of course they align properly again the next day, but every other day they are referencing the wrong table.
Any ideas on what I could do differently to avoid this issue?

For consistency you have to drop and recreate your views, since the relation table - view is established not by name but through Object ID's.

Looks like your real problem is a different one, and this is just a work around that doesn't work either. What is your real problem? (please open a new topic for this)

@FrankHeikens - can you clarify what you mean?  Are you referring to a technology, methodology or something else?

Because of how long it takes to reload and the locks that happen If you solve this problem, you don't have to rename the table anymore. And you don't have this issue with the views.

For consistency you have to drop (or just replace) and recreate your views, since the relation table - view is established internally not by name but through Object ID's.
Here an example
create schema mdm;

create table mdm.item_master as 
select id::int8, round(random() * 1000)::int8 as item
from generate_series(1, 100) as id;

create or replace view mdm.item_master_vw
as select id, item from mdm.item_master;

create table mdm.item_master_swap as 
select id::int8, round(random() * 1000)::int8 as item
from generate_series(1, 100) as id;

--query to visualize the relation table - view
select vtu.view_schema as schema_name,
       vtu.view_name,       
       vtu.table_schema as referenced_table_schema,
       vtu.table_name as referenced_table_name,
       pc."oid" table_oid
from information_schema.view_table_usage as vtu
inner join pg_class pc on vtu.table_name = pc.relname 
where vtu.view_name = 'item_master_vw';

Before executing any change of names



schema_name
view_name
referenced_table_schema
referenced_table_name
table_oid




mdm
item_master_vw
mdm
item_master
42095



alter table mdm.item_master rename to item_master_temp;




schema_name
view_name
referenced_table_schema
referenced_table_name
table_oid




mdm
item_master_vw
mdm
item_master_temp
42095



alter table mdm.item_master_swap rename to item_master;




schema_name
view_name
referenced_table_schema
referenced_table_name
table_oid




mdm
item_master_vw
mdm
item_master_temp
42095



alter table mdm.item_master_temp rename to item_master_swap;




schema_name
view_name
referenced_table_schema
referenced_table_name
table_oid




mdm
item_master_vw
mdm
item_master_swap
42095



So you have to execute again create or replace view ... to get a correct relationship



schema_name
view_name
referenced_table_schema
referenced_table_name
table_oid




mdm
item_master_vw
mdm
item_master
42102



